while pandoc (v3.2) transform markdown to pdf, pandoc use longtable as default, how to change to grid_tables
I am using pandoc v3.2, This is my markdown file:
markdown file
# Test

`This is a table:`

| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    |
| 1    | 1    | 1    | 1    |



+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+

then using the cmd:
pandoc -s test.md -o test.pdf --from=markdown+grid_tables --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont="Microsoft YaHei" -V mainfont="Microsoft YaHei"
the result: 
result
it's always three-line tables, not my want(grid_tables)
who know how to solve it? Thanks!!!
I need to disable the longtable, using pandoc's grid tables. Thanks!!!

The table style used in Markdown has no effect on the style used to output the table.
If you want more lines between cells, then checkout this issue and the solutions offered therein: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/922
